# Multiple python remote attach in VsCode

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, debugging, remote-debugging

I have a docker-compose stack with multiple services.
There is 3 containers using python :
flask
celeryWorker1
celeryWorker2

I'm using debugpy and Python Remote Attach from VsCode to debug, with this launch.json :

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Python: Remote Attach",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "attach",
      "connect": { "host": "0.0.0.0", "port": 6900 },
      "pathMappings": [
        {
          "localRoot": "/path/to/celeryworker1/app",
          "remoteRoot": "/app"
        },
      ],
      "justMyCode": true
    },
  ]
}
```

That's working well when i debug one container.
But my containers are working together and i need to put some breakpoint in all my containers.

I try to add the configuration

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Python: Remote Attach",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "attach",
      "connect": { "host": "0.0.0.0", "port": 6900 },
      "pathMappings": [
        {
          "localRoot": "/path/to/celeryworker1/app",
          "remoteRoot": "/app"
        },
      ],
      "justMyCode": true
    },
    {
      "name": "Python: Remote Attach",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "attach",
      "connect": {
        "host": "0.0.0.0",
        "port": 6901
      },
      "pathMappings": [
        {
          "localRoot": "/path/to/celeryworker2/app",
          "remoteRoot": "/app"
        }
      ],
      "justMyCode": true
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

I have

`pydev debugger: unable to find translation for: "/path/to/celeryworker2/app/app.py" in ["/path/to/celeryworker1/app", "/path/to/celeryworker1/app"] (please revise your path mappings)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "celeryworker1",
      ...
    },
    {
      "name": "celeryworker2",
      ...
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

I found the solution on my own, i set 2 sames name in my configuration.
Working well now when i launch both debugger.